# error in my SQL syntax, although the data I provide matches

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to delete a certain row from my database based on loginName, userName, and title.

However the following error occurs:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near (...)

I have tried deleting only based on loginName, based on userName and based on title, looked up multiple different posts regarding to the problem, but none of them have provided a solution to my problem. I also checked whether the database column names were wrong, which wasn't the case either. I checked whether the includes folder was wrong, or whether I had mistaken the database table cell name, these were all correct, so I am kind of lost right now, and therefore i'm creating this post.

my php script looks like this:

```
$loginName = $_SESSION['loginName'];
$userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
$id = $_POST['id']; //this is for the hiddenTitle 
include_once 'dbConn.php';
$sqli = "DELETE * FROM posts WHERE loginName = ? AND name = ? AND hiddenTitle = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqli)) {
    var_dump($stmt);
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $loginName, $userName, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

this is how I submit my data:

```
function deletePostBtn(del) {
console.log(del.id); //this works
let id = del.id;
let data = {id: id};
$.ajax({
    url: 'deletePost.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); //sends back the error
    }
});
}
```

*So what I am trying to achieve:* Delete the row where loginName = $_POST['loginName'], name = $_POST['userName'] and hiddenTitle = $_POST['id']

Comment: Your statement has **three** parameter placeholders. You're only supplying **one** parameter value. You need to supply values for the other two.

Comment: But when I try to delete based on one placeholder, I get the same error? if you mean with "one parameter value" the id in my ajax call, the other 2 come from a $_SESSION

Comment: The information you swapped to `...` would have told you the error.

Comment: Not really, atleast not apparent enough for me, or else I wouldn't have made a post about it.

Comment: `information [swapped to … Not really told] the error` Please include it verbatim just the same. `following error occurs` during `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`(, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`) or `mysqli_stmt_execute()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `DELETE * FROM ...`. You should have `DELETE FROM ...`

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove `*` from your script. It should be just:

```
DELETE FROM posts ...
```